# How to avoid background color coming from overflow-hidden(equla height div) elemnt css

Tags: html, css

I have set the left column height equal to the right column using css. Now the proble is that. Lefts column background is overlaping on footer.

```css
.body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.left_navigation {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: -9999px;
    padding-bottom: 9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.main_content {
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
}

.footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>header</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="left_navigation">
            <h2>Left Navigation</h2>

        </div>
        <div class="main_content">
            <p>Lorrem Ipsume Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  </p>
            <p>Lorrem Ipsume Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  </p>
            <p>Lorrem Ipsume Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  </p>
            <p>Lorrem Ipsume Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  </p>
            <p>Lorrem Ipsume Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  </p>
            <p>Lorrem Ipsume Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  </p>
            <p>Lorrem Ipsume Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  </p>
            <p>Lorrem Ipsume Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  </p>
            <p>Lorrem Ipsume Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  </p>
            <p>Lorrem Ipsume Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  </p>
            <p>Lorrem Ipsume Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  </p>
            <p>Lorrem Ipsume Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  </p>

            <p>Lorrem Ipsume Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  Lorrem Ipsume  </p>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <ul>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>map</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanchit/5g3oopey/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution would be to add position:relative to your footer:

```
footer {
  position:relative
}
```

(you may have to add z-index depending on your code)

Answer (score 0):

use in style may help you

```
footer
{
    position:relative;
}
.footer ul li
{
    color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using position(except position: static) on elements with z-index helps you about which element stays on front.

I changed you css into this:

```
.body{margin:0;padding:0;}
.left_navigation{background-color:green;float:left;margin-bottom:-9999px;padding-bottom:9999px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;z-index:2;}
.main_content{float:right;background-color:red;position:relative;z-index:1;}
.footer{clear:both;background-color:black;padding:20px;position:relative;z-index:2;}
.content{position:relative;z-index:1;}
.header{position:relative;z-index:3}
```

Try this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/8emnyqq6/1/